# Qualify the quality of two rotations

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

I have two separate rotations which must bring some point to the same ending position.

When I check the dot product of the two (3x3) matrices, it's **I** in most case but not always (seldom strange values).

How would you qualify the match of two rotation from their two matrices?

Comment: try to post your link over [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I just hesitated between here and there before posting... All right! I'll give it a try.

Comment: No problem it just sounded more logic this way.